# Accessibility steps to be taken in HTML for disabled peoples

Tags: html, accessibility

I have created bootstrap HTML design, now I am thinking to enhance my page such that disabled people can also read or view page perfectly. For example, a blind people or a deaf people.

So I think these peoples are using some special screen readers in place of normal browsers, but being a site developer what steps should I take from HTML point of view, so there screen readers can easily tell them the content of my web page.

Please advice if I use some special JS plugin or HTML tag?

Comment: Yup, just pop `<accessible true="yes" />` before your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: In all seriousness: good on you for caring about this. However, “disabled peoples” is a pretty broad description, and it’s impossible to properly describe the accessibility steps (or inclusive design principles) you might want to take in a single Stack Overflow answer. Unfortunately, I don’t know of a great, easy-to-read starter article on the subject. Jukka Korpela wrote [a good one](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jKorpela/acc/index.html), and [the W3C’s Web Accessibility Initiative](http://www.w3.org/WAI/users/Overview.html) has a lot of advice.

Answer (score 6):

You're mistaken saying that blind people use special screen readers *instead of normal browsers*. Yes, they (in fact, we) do use screen readers, but *with* normal browsers.
A screen reader is a piece of software that renders on-screen text into speech and/or [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) so a blind person could perceive it without any help of a sighted person.
In order to make your web page accessible for the blind, follow [Web content accessibility guidelines (WCAG 2.0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/).

As first steps for you to go, check that:

- All significant images have alternative text (`alt` attribute);
- There's no items based uniquely on the color. For example, this is inaccessible:

> Please fill in the form. Fields marked in red are required.

To make this accessible, you can:

- Leave your text as is but mark required fields with the `required` attribute;
- Change your text (and design, accordingly) like this:

> Please fill in the form. Fields marked with an asterisk (*****) are required.

This is accessible indeed. Then, coming back to what you need to check:

- Section titles should be marked with headings (`<h1>` ... `<h6>` tags). And in no way should you use the headings for other things such as making a piece of text bold or just "for a nice look".
- All significant tables should be marked up properly. Use `<caption>`, `<th>` and other useful elements.
- Use HTML 5 semantic markup. Articles, notes, aside elements, sections, navigation blocks and so on should be marked up accordingly.

As for the accessibility for the deaf, there are no such strict requirements except that you should provide visual feedback if your web application has some sound alerts. And, ideally, provide a textual description of every sound and video file (such as an interview) you post on your website.